# Handle Custom error on asp mvc 5 when potentially dangerous occurred

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got the following error when I have `:` in url address:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

I want when my application get an error I can redirect to `/Error/NotFound` action but sometimes it doesn't happen.

For example, I have below code for handle custom errors and it works properly but when I have a potentially dangerous error `controller.Execute()` doesn't fire.

```
 protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var lastException = Server.GetLastError();

        if (lastException.GetType() != typeof(HttpException))
            return;

        var httpException = lastException as HttpException;
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

        if (httpException?.GetHttpCode() == 404 || httpException?.GetHttpCode() == 400)
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");

        if (routeData.Values.Count <= 1)
            return;

        try
        {
            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
```

I realize that when a potentially dangerous error occurred some property of my context such as `CurrentNotification, Handler, Items, Profile, Session and User` is null. I don't know exactly my context is related to this problem or not.

And here is my webconfig:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" maxRequestLength="314572800" enableVersionHeader="false" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
       <remove statusCode="404" />
       <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle all types of errors in your Web.Config like this :

```
  <customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/Error/ErrorPage/404" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/ErrorPage/404" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/ErrorPage/403" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/ErrorPage/500" />
    </customErrors>
```

what i added is the

> defaultRedirect

to handle any type of errors